# What is the size of my Iphone Application when downloaded from the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, app-store, usage-statistics

When my app starts on my device xcode says it uses **3.4MB** of memory.

When I use every feature in my app on my device xcode says it uses **14MB** of memory.

When i submit my app on the appstore, when a user goes to download it, under information what will be the size of my app?

thankyou

Comment: Xcode says?  Are you talking about ram usage?  Does xcode even report storage space?  I believe the app store is going to report the size of the app bundle file that you deliver to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's your RAM usage, and has nothing to do with the download size.

The download size will be the size of all the png images/videos/etc in your application, plus a tiny bit more for the actual code.

To find out the exact number, do an "archive" build, and in the organiser there is an "estimate size" button.

Comment: It might change slightly after the app has gone through the signing/security process, but not by much.

Answer (score 0):

The size of your app and the amount of memory it uses while running will be different because these are different things.

The size of the app is the size of the IPA on disk (which is a zip file) containing:

- code (e.g. armv7 and armv8 slices)
- supporting files (e.g. graphics, sounds etc...)

I would do an Ad-Hoc build in Xcode and look at the IPA produced in order to get the size.

Comment: Under products -->> show in finder --> the application is 1mb, i zipped it and its 0.5mb? is this the app store size?

Comment: Please create an Ad-Hoc build of your app and look at the size of the IPA file as per my answer.  This is the size the App Store will report (there may be minor differences but nothing to worry about).